# P0420 code for 09 Murano

Tags: sensor, catalytic-converter, p0420

I've had several opinions stating my car needs a cat converter but after failing inspection today, the mechanic said it might need ECT sensor changed. I've read previous posts that cat converters should be covered by manufacturers up to 10years...but Nissan dealership told me it's not covered since the car has 87,000 miles. The job itself is pretty pricey...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The info I have found under the federal emissions warranty says it is covered for 8 years or 80,000 miles. If you have had all the service work done at the dealer I would complain to the dealer, the Nissan area rep. and anyone else who will listen. The next thing I would do is get a second opinion. Find out why it failed so it doesn't happen again. Check with a local custom exhaust shop for an estimate. They can install just the converter for way less than the dealer. Several years ago I had both converters replaced for $325 the dealer estimate was $1200 for the "Y" pipe plus installation.